# adding F1 help to a Dialogbox in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have written a windows application, that is own using dialog boxes (NO win form).

I would like to add in some help information.

How can I capture and F1 keypress, and get the help window to open???

Everything I have read only seems to work if you have used a win form.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the HelpProvider component http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx

Comment: from what I can see the Helpprovider, requires a form to be used. I don't have one in the application

Comment: What sort of dialog are you using?